# add anchor tags rel to thumbnails id

Tags: id

Ok, I have a very simple problem. but I'm not good with php, so posting here. the anchor tags of my portfolio items output like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/dianero/portfolio/kahida/" rel="41">kahida</a>
```

& my thumbnails output like:

```
<img width="792" height="535" src="http://localhost/dianero/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/pic3.jpg" class="main-image portfolio  wp-post-image" alt="pic3" id="photo_" style="display: none;">
```

as you can see my thumbnails have id "photo_". what I want is to add the anchor tags rel value to this id. so they look: "photo_41", "photo_42" & so on...

my wp page code is here:

```
<div class="main-interior portfolio" id="portfolio-big-pics" style="display: block;">
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php $extraLastClass = $loop->current_post + 1 === $loop->post_count ? ' main-image-porfolio-main' : '';?>

<?php 
$attributes = array(
    "class" => "main-image portfolio " . $extraLastClass,
    "id" => "photo_",
);
the_post_thumbnail("large", $attributes);
?>

<?php endwhile; ?> 

<?php rewind_posts(); ?> 


    <div class="portfolio-box">
        <h5>Portfolio</h5>
        <ul class="item-list" id="portfolio-list">
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>              
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add ID's to thumbnails like this.

```
<?php 
    $attributes = array(
        "class" => "main-image portfolio " . $extraLastClass,
        "id" => "photo_" . $post->ID,
    );
    the_post_thumbnail( "large", $attributes );
?>
```

Notice I have append `id` with `$post->ID`.